# GithubActions - PlatformError: X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing

Tags: go, github-actions, x11, building-github-actions

I'm trying to create Github Actions for [my repo on Github](https://github.com/Arkadiusz4/meteor-maverick-game).
Everything works fine, until actions come to testing because I have this error:

```
Run cd tests && go test . -v
go: downloading github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.1
go: downloading github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0
go: downloading gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1
2024/03/14 23:49:05 PlatformError: X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing
panic: NotInitialized: The GLFW library is not initialized

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2/internal/cglfw.acceptError({0x0, 0x0, 0x10004?})
    /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2@v2.6.6/internal/cglfw/error.go:184 +0x1f4
github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2/internal/cglfw.panicError(...)
    /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2@v2.6.6/internal/cglfw/error.go:195
github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2/internal/cglfw.WindowHint(0x0?, 0x0?)
    /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2@v2.6.6/internal/cglfw/window.go:317 +0x34
github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2/internal/glfw.WindowHint(...)
    /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2@v2.6.6/internal/glfw/glfw_cglfw.go:347
github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2/internal/ui.initialize()
    /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2@v2.6.6/internal/ui/ui_glfw.go:174 +0x36
github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2/internal/ui.init.2()
    /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2@v2.6.6/internal/ui/ui_glfw.go:159 +0x13
FAIL    github.com/Arkadiusz4/meteor-maverick-game/tests    0.028s
FAIL
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

As you can see there is problem with X11 (I have no clue what's going on here).

I tried to add something to my workflow file:

```
name: Go

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        go-version: [ '1.21.x' ]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v4
        with:
          go-version: '1.21.3'

      - name: Display Go version
        run: go version

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          go get github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2
          go get github.com/stretchr/testify
          sudo apt-get install libxrandr-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libxcursor-dev libxinerama-dev libxi-dev libxxf86vm-dev xorg-dev mesa-utils

      - name: Build
        run: go build -v ./...

      - name: Testing, testing
        run: cd tests && go test . -v
```

It doesn't help, so I also tried to add something to my `main.go`.

```
func main() {
    err := os.Setenv("DISPLAY", ":0")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    g := game.NewGame()

    err = ebiten.RunGame(g)
    err := ebiten.RunGame(g)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        }
}
```

It also doesn't help and I don't have any other thoughts how I can repair this :/

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Something tries to use X11 and fails, so much is right. Where exactly does that happen? It seems like it's downloading and compiling some modules, is that where it happens? If so, that would be a bug in that module, IMHO.

Comment: BTW: Check out https://github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/blob/main/.github/workflows/test.yml. The authors start a virtual X11 server in their actions.

Comment: I'm with Ulrich: the `DISPLAY` env. variable is set and exported by the software (there may be many different) which starts up an [X Window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) session–basically what you'd call a "graphical desktop environment" on a Linux- or *BSD-based system. The variable contains the addres of the socket for X clients to connect to (so that they can communicate with the X server which actually draws their stuff on the screen). There exist virtual X servers (such as Xnest of Xephyr) which are able to "draw" to memory or to nowhere.

Comment: OMG, thank you guys for help. Actually @UlrichEckhardt your answer was correct and now everything works :)